# Generics: how to get type for reuse when using super?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to achieve type-savety across a method signature, but the type relation is lower-bound. I seem to need to use `super T` to restrict the type that the method parameter is restricted by. But I have no means to propagate the passed type to the method's output parameter.

Basically here is what I would like to have:

```java
class Bar {}

class Foo<T extends Bar> {

    // this works perfectly
    public <S extends T> Foo<S> from(S bar) {
        return new Foo<>(bar);
    }

    // incorrect syntax!
    // this should convert the current Foo into a Foo for a sub class ONLY
    public <U super T> Foo<U> fooing(Class<U> clazz) { // <-- this is what I need
        return new Foo<>(clazz);
    }
}
```

Sadly this is incorrect syntax. `super` can only be used with the wildcard operator `?` in front.

The closest I could get was this:

```java
public <U extends Bar> Foo<U> fooing(Class<? extends T> clazz) {...}
```

But it has some undesired effects:

```java
class Bar2 extends Bar {}
...
Foo<Bar2> shouldFail = fooBar.fooing(Bar.class);  // Bar != Bar2
Foo<? extends Bar2> shouldFail2 = fooBar.fooing(Bar.class); // Bar does not extend Bar2
```

The above statements are valid. However **I would like them to fail at compile time.** 
Any ideas on how I can achieve what I need?

Here is a fiddle:
http://ideone.com/scBFLc

Comment: Please put in words what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to re-implement downcasting, ie. `to` should only accept subclasses of the class it's owner represents? In that case: why should the superclass know about it's descendants?

Comment: @mabi You are correct. Except that not the superclass itself (`Bar`) but the (in your words) representation (`Foo`) of the superclass needs to know about the descendents. The reasoning is that `Foo` should be down-gradable without the need of the actual `<? extends Bar>`-instance.

Comment: Guessing: `<U extends T> Foo<U> to(Class<U> clazz)`? This still fails your second example, but I don't understand why you want that: `? super Bar2` says "give me something that is of a class that `Bar2` extends from", which is *true* for `Bar`.

Comment: Also see the [Java Generic FAQ](http://tinyurl.com/o6yk87z)

Comment: I'm halfway to understanding the issue (possibly related: Guava's [`Optional.or`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#or\(T\))), but your code and remarks are confusing. Why does one `Foo` constructor call take an instance, and another take a `Class` token? Also your code comment says "this should convert the current Foo into a Foo for a sub class ONLY" Did you mean *super* class?

Comment: Did you try `public Foo<T> fooing(Class<? super T> clazz) {`?

Comment: @mabi The link brought the solution. And you are right, in that second clause `? super Bar2` should be `? extends Bar2` (fixing it in OP). However your proposed solution is not restrictive enough. I do not want to allow to upgrade from Foo<Bar> to Foo<Bar2>. This is what I was looking for: `public static <A extends Bar, B extends A> Foo<A> fooing(Foo<B> from, Class<A> clazz)`. Please post the link as an answer, so I can mark it.

Comment: @PaulBellora Yes, sorry that is confusing text. I am having trouble explaining the problem, but it is pretty much exactly laid out in mabi's [link](http://tinyurl.com/o6yk87z).

Comment: @Bohemian Sadly, that is not what I need. I need fooing to return something based on what was passed to the function parameter.

Comment: All I'm going to say is that this is making my head spin. In 6 months, you are not likely to remember any of this, and it will greatly confuse your coworkers. I believe you should reconsider your design and try to make it much, much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [Java Generics FAQ](http://tinyurl.com/o6yk87z) point out and you have experienced, that's not really possible with class methods.

The workaround given by the FAQ is to use a static method:

```
public static <A extends Bar, B extends A> Foo<A> upcast(
        Foo<B> from, Class<A> target) { }
```

But I can only echo the concerns of the other commentators: you're setting yourself up for some severe maintenance headaches, especially since I can't envision an actual use case for this piece (in contrast to the FAQ example you're only working on the `Foo` object, not adding to it).

Comment: The concerns are noted and voicing them is appreciated. Let me just add that this is a boiled down example and the actual project provides a plausible use-case for this feature.